Is the X-Men '97 opening sequence showing Gambit and Nightcrawler (dual-wielding swords) fighting enemies a reference to a pre-existing X-Men story?
In the opening sequence of X-Men '97, Season 1, Episode 5, "Remember It", there's a brief clip of Gambit and Nightcrawler (dual-wielding swords) fighting foes wearing green helmets with visors and green body armor, with an arena-like building in the background. This particular scene doesn’t make an appearance within the episode itself.



Similar to other clips shown in the opening sequences of various X-Men '97 episodes, this one seems to be derived from (or inspired by) a scene in the X-Men '97 predecessor, X-Men: The Animated Series. If that's the case, can anyone identify the specific episode it references?
Alternatively, if it's not from the animated series, could it be a reference to a particular X-Men comic book storyline?

Is that Doom guy?
